# wordpress not storing data, only adding new blank entry to database

Tags: wordpress

I have installed a plugin called "Audience Intelligent".

The plugin is still under development. But I want to install it on my site.

**Now the code:**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_audience_intel', 'audience_intel_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_audience_intel', 'audience_intel_ajax');
function audience_intel_ajax() {
$likeit = $_POST['button'];
$postid = $_POST['postid'];

global $wpdb;
$tablename = $wpdb->prefix . "intellike";

$newdata = array(
    'radio' => $likeit,
    'postid' => $postid
);

$wpdb->insert (
    $tablename,
    $newdata
);

if($likeit == 'Yes'){
    $options = get_option('audience_intel_options');
    echo $options['featured'];
}
else { ?>
    <form id="audience_intel_feedback">
        <p><strong><label>What can we do better?</label></strong></p>
        <textarea name="feedback" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $postid;?>" name="postid">
    </form>
    <p><button id="audience_intel_fbutton" class="like">Fix this!</button></button>
<?php }
exit;
}
```

**The Problem**
There is a new entry stored to database. but the feedback text is missing.

[Check on Github](https://github.com/ebinnion/WordPress-Audience-Intel-Plugin/blob/master/audience-intelligence.php) around line 188,

Screenshot of db.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZRxi.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is some problem with the form post variables. Try debugging by echoing the post variable in the ajax call, and print it in the triggering javascript using alert.
Also refer this - http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins. I think in else part also you need to use echo for the new form.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in right direction. The problem is now solved.